# Ocaml refs not retaining its value

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ref

```
(* junk.ml *)
let flag = ref false

let get_flag = !flag

let play_cards card =
    Printf.printf "%s-clause\n" (if card >= 27 && card <= 39 then "true" else "false");
    (flag := if card >= 27 && card <= 39 then true else !flag);
    Printf.printf "check: %B  " get_flag;
```

---

In utop, I imported `junk.ml` and received this output

`val flag : bool ref = {contents = false}                                                  val get_flag : bool = false                                                               val play_cards : int -> unit = <fun>`

I called `play_cards 30;;` and received this output:

`true-clause`
                                                                   `check: true  - : unit = ()`

However, when I called `get_flag` I received `false`. I was wondering if there is a concept of using refs that I misunderstood while writing this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `get_flag` is an immutable name for the value of `!flag` at the time it's defined. You shouldn't expect its value to change; OCaml variables have values that are immutable.

(Some values, like `flag`, are immutable names for things that themselves are mutable. In other words, `flag` is always going to be a name for the same reference, but the value stored in the reference, `!flag`, can change.)

Your comments indicate you want `get_flag` to have different values different times. One way to get this result is to define it as a function:

```
let get_flag () = !flag
```

Now you can call the function, and at each call it returns the value of `flag` at the moment of the call.

```
# let flag = ref false 
  let get_flag () = !flag;;
val flag : bool ref = {contents = false}
val get_flag : unit -> bool = <fun>
# get_flag ();;
- : bool = false
# flag := true;;
- : unit = ()
# get_flag ();;
- : bool = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense as shown, `hearts_broken` and `get_hearts_broken` are never defined. If, however, you have made these definitions somewhere else, then it is no wonder you see the result you're seeing, because `play_cards` doesn't actually modify `flag`, as you seem to assume.

I guess you have renamed `hearts_broken` to `flag` at some point, but forgot to fix `play_cards`? And that happened to not cause an error because you didn't restart the toplevel, so that the old definition was still around?

Comment: I'm very sorry. I accidentally copied down the old code. I edited it now to replace `hearts_broken` with `flag`

Comment: @stumped, with that version I see the output `check: false` as one would expect.